# Limiting splash area for fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Hey there I have a burst pipe simulation I need to do for a client but I need the splash on the ground limited to here in this first image.

[image]

But it’s spreading out too far to the domain edges and filling up.

[image]

Is there someway to limit the splash on the ground?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried with an Effector object?

Comment: if you don't know how to handle the effector...let us know. Unfortunately we don't know how experienced you are. If you don't write that you are a beginner, the answer will be very short... ;)